# getting issue while creating a CRUD operation using sqlite and cordova

Tags: javascript, sqlite, cordova

Hi i am creating a simple sqlite cordova app and i installed the sqlite plugin and  applied the below code

```
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
    var createStatement = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Contacts (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, username TEXT, useremail TEXT)";

    var selectAllStatement = "SELECT * FROM Contacts";

    var insertStatement = "INSERT INTO Contacts (username, useremail) VALUES (?, ?)";

    var updateStatement = "UPDATE Contacts SET username = ?, useremail = ? WHERE id=?";

    var deleteStatement = "DELETE FROM Contacts WHERE id=?";

    var dropStatement = "DROP TABLE Contacts";

    var db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase("AddressBook", "1.0", "Address Book", 200000);  // Open SQLite Database

    var dataset;

    var DataType;

    function initDatabase()  // Function Call When Page is ready.

    {

        try {

            if (!window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase)  // Check browser is supported SQLite or not.

            {

                alert('Databases are not supported in this browser.');

            }

            else {

                createTable();  // If supported then call Function for create table in SQLite

            }

        }

        catch (e) {

            if (e == 2) {

                // Version number mismatch.

                alert("Invalid database version.");

            } else {

               alert("Unknown error " + e + ".");

            }

            return;

        }

    }

    function createTable()  // Function for Create Table in SQLite.

    {

        db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(createStatement, [], showRecords, onError); });

    }

    function insertRecord() // Get value from Input and insert record . Function Call when Save/Submit Button Click..

    {

        var usernametemp = $('input:text[id=username]').val();

        var useremailtemp = $('input:text[id=useremail]').val();
        db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(insertStatement, [usernametemp, useremailtemp], loadAndReset, onError); });

        //tx.executeSql(SQL Query Statement,[ Parameters ] , Sucess Result Handler Function, Error Result Handler Function );

    }

    function deleteRecord(id) // Get id of record . Function Call when Delete Button Click..

    {

        var iddelete = id.toString();

        db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(deleteStatement, [id], showRecords, onError); alert("Delete Sucessfully"); });

        resetForm();

    }

    function updateRecord() // Get id of record . Function Call when Delete Button Click..

    {

        var usernameupdate = $('input:text[id=username]').val().toString();

        var useremailupdate = $('input:text[id=useremail]').val().toString();

        var useridupdate = $("#id").val();

        db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(updateStatement, [usernameupdate, useremailupdate, Number(useridupdate)], loadAndReset, onError); });

    }

    function dropTable() // Function Call when Drop Button Click.. Talbe will be dropped from database.

    {

        db.transaction(function (tx) { tx.executeSql(dropStatement, [], showRecords, onError); });

        resetForm();

        initDatabase();

    }

    function loadRecord(i) // Function for display records which are retrived from database.

    {

        var item = dataset.item(i);

        $("#username").val((item['username']).toString());

        $("#useremail").val((item['useremail']).toString());

        $("#id").val((item['id']).toString());

    }

    function resetForm() // Function for reset form input values.

    {

        $("#username").val("");

        $("#useremail").val("");

        $("#id").val("");

    }

    function loadAndReset() //Function for Load and Reset...

    {

        resetForm();

        showRecords()

    }

    function onError(tx, error) // Function for Hendeling Error...

    {

        alert(error.message);

    }

    function showRecords() // Function For Retrive data from Database Display records as list

    {

        $("#results").html('')

        db.transaction(function (tx) {

            tx.executeSql(selectAllStatement, [], function (tx, result) {

                dataset = result.rows;

                for (var i = 0, item = null; i < dataset.length; i++) {

                    item = dataset.item(i);

                    var linkeditdelete = '<li>' + item['username'] + ' , ' + item['useremail'] + '    ' + '<a href="#" onclick="loadRecord(' + i + ');">edit</a>' + '    ' +

                                                '<a href="#" onclick="deleteRecord(' + item['id'] + ');">delete</a></li>';

                    $("#results").append(linkeditdelete);

                }

            });

        });

    }

    $(document).ready(function () // Call function when page is ready for load..

    {
        ;

        $("body").fadeIn(2000); // Fede In Effect when Page Load..

        initDatabase();

        $("#submitButton").click(insertRecord);  // Register Event Listener when button click.

        $("#btnUpdate").click(updateRecord);

        $("#btnReset").click(resetForm);

        $("#btnDrop").click(dropTable);

    });

    </script>

</head>
<body>

    <h1>
        Form
    </h1>
    <form id="mycontact">
        <fieldset>
            <legend>
                Your details
            </legend>
            <ol>
                <li>
                    <label for="username">
                        Name
                    </label>
                    <input id="username" type="text" placeholder="First and last name" required autofocus pattern="" />
                    <input type="hidden" id="id" />
                </li>
                <li>

                    <label for="useremail">Email</label>

                    <input id="useremail" type="text" placeholder="example@domain.com" required pattern="" />

                </li>
            </ol>
        </fieldset>

        <input type="button" id="btnReset" value="Reset"/>

        <input type="button" id="submitButton"  value="Save"/>

        <input id="btnUpdate" type="button" value="Update"/>

        <input id="btnDrop" type="button" value="Drop"/>

    </form>
    <br />

    <div id="results">


    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

But after executing this code i am getting error in console as"index.html:24 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'openDatabase' of undefined  and im really confused what i did wrong  and can any one help me out with this issue

Answer (score 0):

The error is explicitly telling you that `window.sqlitePlugin` doesn't exist at the time you're trying to make the open database call.

First you should make sure that you wait until Cordova has finished loading before trying to use the SQLite plugin by wrappering your open database in Cordova's `deviceready` event:

```
var db = null;

document.addEventListener('deviceready', function() {
  db = window.sqlitePlugin.openDatabase({name: 'demo.db', location: 'default'});
});
```

This example is shown right at the top of the plugin's documentation:
https://github.com/litehelpers/Cordova-sqlite-storage